# Show that for any open subset of $\Bbb R$, there is a fraction with prime terms that belongs to it

Tags: prime-numbers, real-numbers, approximation-theory, prime-gaps

Be $\Bbb P\Bbb Q$ the set of all fractions $f_{m,n}=\frac{p_m}{p_n}$ whose numerador and denominator are both prime numbers.

i) Show that for any open set $A\subset \Bbb R^+$, there is at least one fraction $f \in \Bbb P\Bbb Q$ such that $f \in A$

ii) Show that there are infinitely many elements of  $\Bbb P\Bbb Q$ that belong to any open  set $A\subset \Bbb R^+$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: I try to find an approximative representation of real numbers by fractions with prime terms  labelled by its prime orders: m,n

Comment: Fractions with prime terms have some nice features. For example, they are closed under inversion.

Comment: The difficulty could be overwhelming. It seems that you are not even sure if it is true.

Comment: Sure. Although I 'feel' that the assertion should be is true, I don't see an easy way to show i). ii) is trivial once given i).

Comment: There is a (very difficult) theorem that for $n$ large enough there is always a prime between $n$ and $n+n^{0.535}$. See e.g., https://primes.utm.edu/notes/gaps.html You can use this to solve your problem. There may be easier proofs.